# Unable to find logic of checkbox search?

Tags: java, javascript, sql, jsp, servlets

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="float_left dshadow" style="border:1px solid gray;width:300px;height:900px;margin:40px 0 0 70px;">
        <div style="width:100%;height:50px;background:black;"> <h3 class="text_center padd_top_2 color_fff">Filter Products By</h3></div>
        <div class="filter_tab" id="price1">Price<i class="icon-angle-up color_0 font17 float_right" id="Up" ></i><i class="icon-angle-down color_0 font17 float_right hide" id="down" o></i></div>
        <ul class="margin_left20 list_filter" id="price_3">
            <li><input type="checkbox"  class="margin_right10" >1000-2000</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox"  class="margin_right10" >2000-3000</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox"  class="margin_right10" >3000-4000</li>
        </ul>
         <div class="filter_tab" id="size1">Size<i class="icon-angle-up color_0 font17 float_right" id="Up1" ></i> <i class="icon-angle-down color_0 font17 float_right hide" id="down1" ></i></div>
        <ul class="margin_left20 list_filter" id="size">
            <li><input type="checkbox" class="margin_right10" >Small</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" class="margin_right10" >Medium</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" class="margin_right10" >Large</li>
        </ul>
          <div class="filter_tab" id="brand1">Brand<i class="icon-angle-up color_0 font17 float_right" id="Up2" ></i><i class="icon-angle-down color_0 font17 float_right hide" id="down2"></i></div>
        <ul class="margin_left20 list_filter" id="brand">
            <li><input type="checkbox" class="margin_right10" >Dell</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" class="margin_right10" >HP</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" class="margin_right10" >Sony</li>
        </ul>
```

Currently I am working on this search but i want to call an ajax function on click of each checkbox and run a database query and fetch results and when checkbox is unchecked i want to delete corresponding divs from the JSP page.I have tried different logics on my servlet but failed to get relevant result.Could anybody guide me how to code servlet and make logic of this search.

EDIT:

Basically i want to know which query to run at Servlet which can fulfil all the checkboxes that user have selected.

Comment: Do you ask about javascript code or server side code?

Comment: @Ennosigaeon server side  code that is java code.But if you could provide any alternative how to process it using client side code you are welcome.

Comment: Which MVC framework do you use (if any) ? I see you speak of servlet but did you code them implementing the Servlet interface or do you use a particular framework to assist you on this matter ?

Comment: @m4rtin I am using Hibernate framework and i am implementing the Servlet interface for servlet.

Comment: It is still not clear to me what you exact problem is. Do you ask how to submit to the server, which Checkbox was clicked? Or do you want to know how to load the data from the database in the JSP?

Comment: @Ennosigaeon Actually i know how to check which checkbox was clicked and how to load data to JSP.All i want to know how to manage this search using a single or using 2-3 queries.

Comment: Ok so here's what I would do and as you can guess from @Ennosigaeon answer, there will be a bit of both world. Client side, you'll have to bind a JS function to the change or click event of each of your checkbox. That JS function will gather all your checkboxes state and send them server-side using an AJAX call. Then server side, only use 1 entry point in your servlet and only code 1 hibernate query in your persistence layer to search according to the checkboxes state you received from the client. I don't advice to delete specific div from one search to another. (1/2)

Comment: Each time a checkbox value is changed, it should trigger another search so just wipe out the entire previous result set in your view (do it in JS) and recreate the div showing your results. Server-side, you'll have to decide which format the result will be sent in to your client. I advice JSON because you will parse them in JS but the choice is yours. I would post the resulting code as an answer but I don't have time right now so another SO member will do it or you'll have to do a bit more reading ;) Cheers (2/2)

Comment: The query highly depends on you database structure. Without information about your database I can only guess what the best solution is. Maybe it is possible to generate the query string dynamically using the "BETWEEN" keyword for numeric limits (like the price) and the "IN" keyword you string restrictions (like manufactor). However, your tags for this question are totally wrong.

Comment: I do agree with @Ennosigaeon, if you're actually only looking for the hibernate query, my comments are totally off topic (I thought you were looking for a general solution to your problem).

Comment: @m4rtin actually i am looking for both hibernate query and to know in which state i should send data.I should send brand name by concatenating them or how.

Comment: @Ennosigaeon I am using MYSQL and i have 1 table named Products where everything is places that is color,brand etc

Comment: @m4rtin if you could post an answer to it i will be very happy that is javascript and java code.